# How to obtain difference between random effects groups from the mean interaction coefficient in lmer models

Tags: lme4, mixed-models, random-effects

I'm trying to fit a mixed model with one categorical and one continuous predictor in interaction and a random slope and intercept term (and some models with just the random intercept as well).

Conceptually:

```
leaf_phenology ~ leaf_habit * watertable_distance + (1+watertable_distance|species)
```

or

```
leaf_phenology ~ leaf_habit * watertable_distance + (1|species)
```

How do I extract from a merMod object (generated with lmer) how much each group (each species) of my random factor deviate from the mean interaction coefficient of the model? Because I want to know how much the effect of the continuous predictor (watertable_distance) depends on the categorical predictor (leaf_habit) per group (species)?

I've tried to explore the ranef, coef, VarCorr.merMod, and broom.mixed::augment outputs, but I'm not exactly sure about where to find the effect I described above, or even if I will need to calculate it manually instead of extract from the model object.

Thanks in advance!